# NPM - what is the common practice to manage dependencies during production deploy

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json

We have a frontend project using webpack and npm to manage dependencies.

When we hook up to jenkin to automate the deployment process to `test` and to `production`, the following is what we do :-

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. `npm install --production`
3. build the frontend artifacts

Is that the right approach that to remove the node_modules everytime and reinstall everything again ?

We used to do `npm update`, but we hit some dependencies problem a few times in our build failed, so we switch to remove the node_modules and reinstall everything in every deploy.

I felt we are doing extra work there, and I would want to know what is the common practice in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) is designed to update the versions of a package, not install any missing dependencies.

Running `npm install` when you already have some packages in your `node_modules` folder will install any not installed packages in your `package.json` file.

Also, i'd advise setting up a [shrinkwrap file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to ensure the versions of the dependencies are the same across all machines.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between `npm update` and `npm install`.  But what is the common practice during deployment ?

Do you run both?   For my case, I basically delete all `node_modules` and start fresh again.  

I would want to know how other people are doing it in automated fashion.

Comment: And also, the shrinkwrap file is for module author to lock down version?  Am I correct ?

Comment: shrinkwrap should only be used for applications, rather than libraries. Are you an author of a library, or an application?

Comment: An application.  Okay, let me look into shrinkwrap a little bit then.   

The problem I have is sometimes someone add new stuff in package.json or modify the package version, and they could potentially  on different node version. it breaks the build sometimes.  I wonder what is the best way to deal with that.